# #pragma pack, template typedefs, and struct alignment

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++, gcc, memory-alignment

Using Visual Studio or gcc, if I've got

```
#pragma pack(push, 16)

typedef std::map<uint32_t, uint32_t> MyIntMap;

#pragma pack(pop)
```

then later:

```
#pragma pack(push, 8)

MyIntMap thisInstance;

#pragma pack(pop)
```

What is the structure alignment of thisInstance?   That is, for a typedef'd template class, does pragma pack take effect at the place of the typedef or at the place of a variable definition?  If it's the latter, what's a good workaround to get a type with consistent alignment across files?

Answer (score 5):

In your code, the `#pragma pack` will have no effect. It only does anything when it's in effect around the definition of a struct or class, not around a typedef or anything. Neither does it have any effect around that variable definition.

You can see the usage here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2e70t5y1(v=VS.100).aspx

Specifically:

> pack takes effect at the first struct, union, or class declaration after the pragma is seen. pack has no effect on definitions.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what about forward declarations? And what about classes packed with this pragma and forward declarations thereof? Do I need to repeat the pragma there?

Comment: @arne it has no effect for forward declarations, only on class definitions. You can see my test here: http://pastebin.com/4YAHrYW3