# How can I pack a template class?

Tags: c++, templates, pack

I have use a packed template class. According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8075437/pragma-pack-template-typedefs-and-struct-alignment) I should wrap it with #pragma pack as in this example:

```
#include <iostream>

#pragma pack(1)
template<typename X>
struct S {
 int a;
 X b;
};
#pragma pack()

int main()
{
  std::cout << sizeof(S<char>) << "\n";
}
```

Using gcc-4.4.7 on my centOS6, the program output 8, which means pack(1) didn't work. Then I tried to change main() to:

```
int main()
{
  std::cout << sizeof(S<char>) << "\n";

#pragma pack(1)
  std::cout << sizeof(S<char>) << "\n";
#pragma pack()
}
```

Surprisingly it still didn't work. If I comment out the first line in main() then it works. So my question is how to use pack on a template class instantiation? Is there anyway to use both packed and unpacked template class in the same program?

Update: If I use gcc-5.2.1, then it output 5 correctly. Also for the following program, I get opposite results (5 with gcc-4.4.7 and 8 with 5.2.1):

```
template<typename X>
struct S {
 int a;
 X b;
};

int main()
{
#pragma pack(1)
 std::cout << sizeof(S<char>) << "\n";
#pragma pack()
}
```

Why do gcc-4.4.7 and 5.2.1 behave differently? Which one is correct? Is there anyway to get consistent result with different versions of gcc?

Comment: I tried your code using gcc 6.1.1 and the output is 5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works for me

```
#include <iostream>
#pragma pack(1)
namespace Packed
{
    template<typename X>
    struct S {
     int a;
     X b;
    };

    template struct S<char>;
}
#pragma pack()

namespace NotPacked
{
    template<typename X>
    struct S {
     int a;
     X b;
    };

    template struct S<char>;
}

int main()
{
  std::cout << sizeof(Packed::S<char>) << "\n";
  std::cout << sizeof(NotPacked::S<char>) << "\n";
}
```

You can put definition of S to header (but without #pragma once) and avoid code duplication:

```
#pragma pack(1)
namespace Packed
{
#include "S.h"
}
#pragma pack()

namespace NotPacked
{
#include "S.h" 
}
```

Comment: Nope, I got 8 and 8 using gcc-4.4.7.

Comment: Yes, for old versions explicit instantiation required, I've edited